# Using Powershell to loop through Excel files and check if Spreadsheet name exists

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will loop through each excel file in the given directory, check the file for a specifically named worksheet, and then copy that file to another location if it's a match.

Please see below for what I've already tried:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("microsoft.office.excel")

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$tempLocation = "C:\Test\"     # Path to read files
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Test

ForEach ($file in $files)
{
#Check for Worksheet named TestSheet

     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
     $WorkSheets = $WorkBook.WorkSheets

     foreach ($WorkSheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
     If ($WorkSheet.Name -eq "TestSheet")
    {$path = $tempLocation + "\" + $file
         Write "Saving $path"
         Copy-Item c:\Test\$file c:\Confirmed}
     Else {Write "$path does not contain TestSheet"}
     $WorkBook.Close()
}
}
```

This script returns no errors in PowerShell, but just sits there without writing anything or copying any files.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:  Here's my final script that is now running successfully**

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
$tempLocation = "C:\Source"     # Path to read files
$targetlocation = "C:\Target"
Write "Loading Files..."
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Source
Write "Files Loaded."
ForEach ($file in $files)
{
#Check for Worksheet named TestSheet
     $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
     $Excel.visible = $false
     $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $WorkSheets = $WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "TestSheet"}

     if($WorkSheets) {
     $path = $tempLocation + "\" + $file
     $dest = $targetlocation + "\" + $file
     Write "Saving $path"
     $WorkBook.SaveAs($dest)
     }
     $Excel.Quit()
     Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
}
Read-host -prompt "The Scan has completed.  Press ENTER to close..."
clear-host;
```

Comment: I'd guess there are no worksheets called `TestSheet` as that's the only condition that can be met where your script really does anything

Comment: Does the syntax look correct?  The sheet I'm looking for may be a "Very Hidden" worksheet.  Would it still be recognized programmatically?  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ha, well spotted, you just answered your own question! The test for comparison in Powershell uses `-eq` not `=`, so you need: `$WorkSheet.Name -eq "TestSheet"`

Comment: @acro444, thanks for the error correction!  However, it still just sits there.  I even added an `Else` to my logic.  Please see my updated post and let me know if I'm just trying to do something stupid...  The directory is definitely correct, and I'm executing in powershell from `PS C:\>`, so it's nothing like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several issues with my script's logic.  The following script ran successfully!  It took hours of research...

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
$tempLocation = "C:\Source"     # Path to read files
$targetlocation = "C:\Target"
Write "Loading Files..."
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Source
Write "Files Loaded."
ForEach ($file in $files)
{
#Check for Worksheet named TestSheet
     $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
     $Excel.visible = $false
     $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $WorkSheets = $WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "TestSheet"}

     if($WorkSheets) {
     $path = $tempLocation + "\" + $file
     $dest = $targetlocation + "\" + $file
     Write "Saving $path"
     $WorkBook.SaveAs($dest)
     }
     $Excel.Quit()
     Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
}
Read-host -prompt "The Scan has completed.  Press ENTER to close..."
clear-host;
```

Comment: This is inefficient. You don't want to open and close Excel for every file; you only want to close and open the workbook.

Comment: Good catch.  How would you update the script to ensure it opens and closes the workbook instead of the whole program?  Thanks!

Comment: Move the first three, non-comment, lines in the `ForEach` loop to outside before you enter the loop; then move the last two lines in the `ForEach` loop outside after you exit the loop. The algorithm is 1)Open Excel before entering the loop 2)Loop: open the workbook then close the workbook 3)Exit the loop and exit Excel. You only want one ComObject you don't want to be recreating it everytime.

Comment: Also, I'm unsure if you deal with macro workbooks but I like setting the VBA to off `$Excel.AutomationSecurity = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity]::msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`. Less processing time to open the workbook.

Comment: @MadTomVane, Good advice.  And yes, they were macro-enabled.  So that'd be a good adjustment as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("microsoft.office.excel")
```

($Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application is sufficient here)

I don't think you're referencing the full path to your Excel files.  Try modifying this line:

```
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
```

Amend to:

```
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
```

Additionally, consider adding a filter to your Get-ChildItem command, if there are sub-directories or non-Excel files, they will cause errors:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Test -filter "*.xls"
```

Comment: Thanks, @nimizen.  I'll give this a shot.  It's a folder full of over 10,000 files, so it may just take a minute to kick off... maybe I'm being too impatient.

Comment: Hey, @nimizen.  PowerShell is still just sitting there... I've been waiting for over an hour and it hasn't written any results.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!