# How to *quickly* convert many .txt files into .xls files

Tags: excel, vba

Update: I just found out that someone with a more powerful server is going to work on the task I was assigned, so it's fine that I didn't make this program fast enough. However, the answer below (automating Excel) helped make the program three times faster, so I'd recommend it to someone with fewer (but still many) files.

I'm trying to convert many (over 300,000) .txt files into .xls files. I found out how to do it here:

[Batch Convert TXT to XLS Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305892/batch-convert-txt-to-xls-using-vba)

But it's really slow (in over an hour, it only converted ~200 our of 300,000 of the files), even though the files aren't that big.

I tried speeding it up by turning off ScreenUpdating, but I wasn't able to turn off ScreenUpdating successfully. Can someone explain where in the to turn off ScreenUpdating so that my code will run quicker? Or, better yet, any ideas for a more efficient program?

Here's the code:

```
Sub TXTconvertXLS()

'Variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String
Dim strDir As String

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Directories
strDir = 'path went here
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.txt")

 Do While strFile <> ""

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
        With wb
            .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
            .Close False   '<-already saved in the line directly above
        End With
    Set wb = Nothing
    strFile = Dir   '<- stuffs the next filename into strFile
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid the `ScreenUpdating=false` are not relevant to _open workbooks_.  To speed up the process, I think you should use other language to do that, and also hide the **Excel**.  I believe most of the time your program are busy with the GUI stuff (open the workbook and update the interface of Excel itself).

Comment: Are you essentially trying to only rename the 300k files?

Comment: What is the purpose of saving the txt files as xls files? What value does that add in your bigger picture of business needs?

Comment: How large are the files are where are you saving them to (local drive or network)?  Have you tried timing which part is the slowest?  Do you really have one folder with 300k files?

Comment: What do these text files look like? If they are csv files, perhaps just change the file extensions from `.txt` to `.cvs`. Standard Windows file associations when Office is installed will by default open such files in Excel.

Comment: I'm not just trying to rename the files - the data needs to be imported into excel from each file (which I can only open in notepad before the conversion). I need to convert them so I can run a different macro on all the excel files. Each file is 1-10 kb. I realized that I'm saving them on OneDrive. @TimWilliams would saving them on the local drive be faster?

Comment: @JohnColeman they only open in notepad, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Yes, `.txt` files open in notepad (as a default) but `.csv` files open in Excel (as a default). What do the files look like? They might already be csv files saved with a `.txt` extension and simply need their extension changed. Also -- if your goal is to run a macro on each file, can't the macro be tweaked so that it opens a `.txt` file to get the needed data rather than a `.xls` file? Changing one macro seems like less work than changing 300k files.

Comment: Saving to OneDrive is going to be a lot slower than saving to a local disk

Comment: @JohnColeman File Explorer lists them all as "Text Documents" - so wouldn't that mean they aren't .csv files. How can I change their extension?

Comment: @TimWilliams I ran the program without OneDrive syncing, and it ran a bit faster but terminated after a few minutes for some reason (and it wasn't fast enough anyways).

Comment: File Explorer lists them as text documents because they have a `.txt` extension. A csv file is also just a simple text file. `.txt` isn't the only extension used for data which is stored as text. Your file is a csv file if it consists of a series of lines where each line is a list of comma-separated values.  See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I would also suggest saving the converted files into a different directory from where you're opening the txt files - in case that causes issues by slowing down the Dir() operations.  Unanswered question - are your files really all in one folder?   Having a large number of files in a single folder might also be an issue which would impact performance

Comment: Are you also sourcing the txt files from OneDrive?

Comment: @TimWilliams How do I save the files in a different directory? Also, I have all 300,000 files in one folder. Would splitting it up into multiple folders help? Then, would I have to run the code on one folder at a time?

Comment: To save to a different folder: `.SaveAs "C:\Converted\" & Replace(wb.Name, ".txt", ".xls"), 50`  As for having that many files in a single folder - you are well below the technical limit but it might be having some practical effect.  An easy test would be to copy (eg) 1000 files to a different (local) folder and compare how long it takes to process those vs. processing 1000 files from the folder with the total collection.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm pretty sure I'm not sourcing the txt files from OneDrive. It's hard to tell on my Windows 10 laptop, where everything seems connected to OneDrive though. I think everything is stored on both my PC and OneDrive (that's the impression I got in settings). I paused syncing to run this code.

Comment: " I need to convert them so I can run a different macro on all the excel files". Keep talking - what are you really doing? My guess is you're doing data processing the hard way - through excel. You should consider the big picture and use the right tool for the job. Import the text files into a database and process in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of options which should be quicker.

1. Use `Powershell` (saves the code below in Notepad as say *xx.ps1*, update your source directory and run)
2. Automate Excel in a hidden instance rather than in your current one.

*Powershell*

Drawing on https://superuser.com/questions/875831/using-powershell-is-it-possible-to-convert-an-xlsx-file-to-xls and [Using Powershell to loop through Excel files and check if Spreadsheet name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101259/using-powershell-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-check-if-spreadsheet-name-exist)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.txt
Write "Loading Files..."

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files)
{

     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilepath = $file.Fullname -replace ".{4}$"
     $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".xls"
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,56)   

}
  Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
  $Excel.Quit()
```

*Automate Excel*

```
Sub TXTconvertXLS2()

Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String
Dim strDir As String

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
With objExcel
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

    'Directories
    strDir = "c:\temp\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.txt")

    'Loop
     Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
            With wb
                .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
                .Close False   '<-already saved in the line directly above
            End With
        Set wb = Nothing
        strFile = Dir   '<- stuffs the next filename into strFile
    Loop

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Quit
Set objExel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "operate Excel in a hidden instance rather than in your current one"? I was just going to copy and paste the block of code for "Automate Excel" to replace my current macro

Comment: I tried the "Automate Excel" macro, and it made the program three times quicker! However, that's still too slow and I just found out that someone with a more powerful server is going to work on the task I was assigned, so it's ok that I didn't make it fast enough.

Comment: If you want to process 300,000 text files, you need a database, not an intermediate excel macro

Comment: @studiis good that it is quicker, but agree with the comment from Nick that your need a new approach (if possible) to get the orders of magnitude you need. Did you try the PowerShell approach?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Someone could have mentioned that earlier lol... Thanks though

Comment: @brettdj I couldn't get the Powershell method to work because I've never used Powershell before and by the time I got it to run the path to my folder couldn't be found. But someone else is taking care of this task. I really appreciate your lengthy response above, though.

Comment: @studiis no probs cheers. I will take this up myself with the Powershell gurus - I think though even though Powershell is very efficient any automation of Excel will be too slow.

Comment: have posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626160/automate-the-conversion-of-excel-files

Comment: The database approach is 'non trivial' - we don't know what your macro does. But we do know that processing 300,000 by converting into excel then running a macro is using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Thanks.  The Powershell sample works for me, but only to XLS format.  Tried outputting to XLSX instead.  It created the file, but its corrupt and data cannot be viewed.  Can powershell perform the same operation but output XLSX instead of XLS?

Answer (score 0):

To convert from CSV to XLSX instead, use this powershell variation of brettdj's example:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$files = Get-ChildItem C:\test\*.csv
Write "Loading Files..."

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files)
{

     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilepath = $file.Fullname -replace ".{4}$"
     $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".xlsx"
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,51)

}

$Excel.Quit()  
Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
```